# Batch API passing data to finished function

Tags: 7, batch-operations

I am creating a batch import and I would like to pass two different counts to my finished function. For example in my 'operations' function I check for an NID if it exists update the node if it doesn't then create it.

In my 'finished' function I want to do something like:

```
 batch_import_finished($success, $results, $operations) {
   if ($success) {
     $message ='Nodes created: '.$nodesCreated. '<br />';
     $message .='Nodes updated: '.$nodesUpdated;
   }
   else {
     $message = 'some errors';
   }

  drupal_set_message($message);
}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, make sure you set the *finished process* in your batch process.

```
$batch = array(
      'title' => t('Merging content ...'),
      'operations' => array(
         array('batch_import_import', array($col1, $col2),  //Note we pass 2 variables here.
       ),
      'finished' => 'batch_import_finished', // set this!
      'init_message' => t('Connectng to the base site ...'),
      'progress_message' => t('Processed @current out of @total.'),
      'error_message' => t('An error occurred during processing'),
      'progressive' => FALSE
    );
...
batch_set('admin/content');
```

Then, in your worker function, you can take the last argument passed to it as $context.

For an example, from above example above, your worker function should be something like this:

```
function batch_import_import($col1, $col2, &$context) {
  //do the stuff.
  if (!isset($context['results']['created'], $context['results']['updated'])) {
    $context['results']['created'] = 0;
    $context['results']['updated'] = 0;
  }
  $context['results']['created']++; // is_new == TRUE or some logic.
  $context['results']['updated']++; // add some logic to determine created or updated.
}
```

and then in the finish function, you get `$context['results']` as the second argument.

```
batch_import_finished($success, $results, $operations) {
   if ($success) {
     $message = t('Nodes created: @count', array('@count' => $results['created'])).'<br />';
     $message .= t('Nodes updated: @count', array('@count' => $results['updated']));
   }
   else {
     $message = t('some errors');
   }

  drupal_set_message($message);
}
```

I have also corrected the $message as you can use `t()` function here. 
Note that you pass `$context` by reference. 
See batch_api examples for more information. This is just some code copied from a module I was developing the other day.

In the finished function, `$operations` contain unprocessed items.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your example and I get an Notice: Undefined variable: col1, Notice: Undefined variable: col2. Here is my operations - array('node_import_worker', array($new_node, $col1, $col2)). Don't I need to set the value of $col1 and $col2 ?

Comment: I just set the values before the function and everything seems to work, Thanks!